# Place 2 Buttons horizontally

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to place 2 buttons horizontally with space between them.

Any simple html and css code snippet someone could share ?

I couldn't find any good example

Comment: Why doesn't "<button>1</button> <button>2</button>" do what you want?

Comment: This is insanely simple. Exactly what @David suggested immediately came to mind for me. If you wish to specify a margin for those buttons, then just set it via CSS.

Comment: I need them to have space between them.

Comment: I'm really new at web development. Sorry for the novice questions

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways, here is a very simple example with floats:

https://jsfiddle.net/dbb8xk38/

```
<button class="button-1">Example</button>
<button class="button-2">Example 2</button>

button{
  float: left;
}

.button-2{
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I would strongly encourage you to go w3school CSS tutorial, it will teach you amazing things.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Note: In case with buttons you don't even have to float them, by default they will come next to each other.  But with elements such as a div, you would need to float.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to achieve with the rest of the page, in terms of layout and what styles you wish to apply to your other buttons and other HTML controls.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

HTML:

```
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

The HTML/CSS above will place a 20 pixel margin at the left of EVERY button. If you simply need to apply it to one button, then you'll need a separate class or some inline style to do that.

E.g.

CSS:

```
.buttonSpaced {
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

And then just apply this style to the 2nd button only.

HTML:

```
<button class="buttonSpaced">Button 2</button>
```

Or you could just do it inline, if it's not likely to be used again...

```
<button style="margin-left:20px;">Button 2</button>
```